# how to display the content of meta_box?

Tags: php, wordpress

I take the code from a former developer. two metas boxes have been created for post types.
Here is the code:

```
/* custom meta box */
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "publication_meta_boxes");

function publication_meta_boxes() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'publications') {
        add_meta_box("publication-text-wp-editor", "titre de la publication", "publication_text_wp_e", "publications", "normal", "low");
        add_meta_box("link-wp-box", "référence", "link_wp_box", "publications", "normal", "low");
    }
}

function publication_text_wp_e() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $publication_text_wp_e = $custom["publication_text_wp_e"][0];
    wp_editor($publication_text_wp_e, 'publication_text_wp_e');
}

function link_wp_box() {

    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, "link_wp_box", true);
    ?>
    <input style="width:100%" placeholder="Link title" type="text" name="link_wp_box[link_title]" value="<?= $custom['link_title'] ?>"/><br/>
    <input style="width:100%" placeholder="Link href" type="text" name="link_wp_box[link_href]" value="<?= $custom['link_href'] ?>"/>
    <?php
}
```

How to display them in frontend. I have tried quite a few things but nothing is displayed.

thank you in advance

cordially

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function in a plugin or the functions.php file of your theme to get the post meta field values:

```
function getPostMeta($postID){
    $your_key = 'link_wp_box';
    $value = get_post_meta($postID, $your_key , true);

    return $value;
}
```

Then call the function in your single.php or where you want to display the value.

```
getPostMeta(get_the_ID());
```